# Upload and fetch images in PERN stack Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

So, the scenario is:

I'm working on PERN Stack.

I want to get an image file from the user and upload it to **EC2(AWS)** and store its public path **(like: www.mydomain/uploads/images/pic1.png)** in the database so that I can display it in the front-end by fetching that public image path from the database.

**What I'm doing right now:**

I am getting an image from the user and storing it in **an S3 bucket**, and I'm also getting a public URL(amazon S3 bucket URL) to display that image in the front end.

But, the issue is:

My domain is (**sub.example.com**); I want to upload and get an image URL like this (**sub.example.com/uploads/images/image1.png**).

I don't know how to configure a domain with an S3 bucket to get an image URL like this (sub.example.com/uploads/images/image1.png).

**Can you guide me:**

> How to configure a domain with an S3 bucket to get a public URL(like:
> sub.example.com/uploads/images/image1.png) for images?

OR

> How can I upload and fetch images using the Amazon EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use exactly same domain in your express server and s3 url, I only come up with this solutation. Because you couldn't let one CNAME point to different domain (express domain + s3 domain) unless you use proxy.

Use part of express as proxy to fetch s3 image data, and give it back to users.
This is an example code.

```js
// setup path same as s3 object key path
app.get('/uploads/images/:imageFile', async (req, res) => {
    const imageFile = req.params.imageFile
    const imageUrl = `https://{s3.domain}/upload/images/${imageFile}`

    // This simulate to fetch image from the s3
    const response = await axios.get(imageUrl, {
        responseType: "stream"
    })

    // you could set different content-type by content-type from response of s3 url.
    res.setHeader("content-type", "image/png")
    response.data.pipe(res)
})
```